# deviceReady not working in PhoneGap application, how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, cordova

I have a simple PhoneGap application as fallows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PhoneGap powered App</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true); 
        function onDeviceReady() {
            alert ('123');
        }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="onDeviceReady()">
        <div data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>title</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">   
                <h2>Begin by inserting your credentials.</h2>
                ...
            </div><!-- /content -->

        </div><!-- /page -->

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function () {

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What happens here is that the alert `alert ('123');` never gets fired. But if I take out the other JavaScript code and leave only the alert it is fired.

Also if I use `$(document).ready(function () { alert ('123'); }` I get the alert.

What is happening here, why the `deviceready` is not getting fired?

Any ideas?

Comment: You're defining the function AFTER using it. Put the function definition ABOVE the `document.addEventListener(...)` call and it should work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try it this way :

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
      alert("123");
 },true);
```

Comment: Not sure. May be syntax problem. Try like this : document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), true); or try changing the name of the function like myDeviceReady().

Comment: There's no way `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), true);` could work because you are passing the return value of `onDeviceReady` which is undefined but addEventListener expects a function.

Comment: @Patrioticcow Try writing your line `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true); ` below the function definition rather than above it.

Answer (score 16):

What @GPRathour provided works because `document.addEventListener()` is listening for `deviceready`, then if true, running your alert function.  I didn't work how you had it because of two reasons:

1) when the DOM loaded and got down to your body tag it was calling OnDeviceReady() and the listener never got the call, so phonegap doesn't know it's ready to run.

2) you would have to call your listener from within a function and use 'false':

```
function init(){
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady(){
  alert('123');
}

<body onload="onDeviceReady()"></body>
```

Check out the phonegap API as to why to use false instead of true in your listener, has to do with the default setting, but it's worth the read to understand how phonegap listeners work.

Comment: For false vs. true in third arg, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564323/what-does-the-third-parameter-false-indicate-in-document-addeventlistenerdev

Comment: @Godzilla74 is the function name in onload property correct? Wouldn't be it init()?

Answer (score 10):

Just in case you have the same problem as me, I didn't know is needed to include the cordova.js script in your index.html, you don't have to provide the file or the reference, just include this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

and then Cordova will use the library when compiling, after that the event is dispatched.

Comment: remember to REMOVE the default index.js leftover from the blank app.

Answer (score 6):

this code work for me

```
<body onload="init()"></body>

function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use the Cordova API
}
```

happy coding.......

Answer (score 5):

When using **PhoneGap 3.0** with **WP8** Device Ready will not work because **Phonegap.js** is NOT INCLUDED in the Visual Studio solution.

The solution is to include it manually for now.

Answer (score 3):

Add you event listener for deviceready inside you doc ready...

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true); 
    });

    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert ('123');
    }
</script>
```

You dont want to call onDeviceReady() as this will run the function when you add the listener...

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for unfired ondeviceready event on one or more platform, is when you try use cordova/phonegap js of the wrong platform.

Comment: To be totally clear, if you use the android version of cordova-xx.js on ios, it will not work, and since they are all named the same, this can some times happen.

Answer (score 1):

Check the versions of the Cordova/phonegap library/jar files that you have added with the project (under libs) and the < script src="~/Scripts/cordova-3.0.0.js"/> script that you are referring in the HTML files. If there is a mismatch, the < script/> may not be able to refer it in the project. So that cordova fails to execute it's functionality.

Comment: I had this issue because I had forked an example that was using cordova-1.6.1.js, but using the Phonegap v3.4 CLI. I fixed it by replacing the cordova JS file with the one from the 3.4 release (https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/releases/tag/3.4.0).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to remove 
meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="...

Answer (score 0):

You're binding a handler to deviceready before you've defined the handler.

Correct would be:

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    alert('123')
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

And obviously your phonegap-2.0.0.js file (or other version) should be included in the file before this point.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, but I won't downvote but please read about [Function Hoisting](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/) in javascript to avoid wrong answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure below path is correct and both are need to be included into html :

```
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        });

        function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("inside onDeviceReady");
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm see in your code one problem, in the method, you need add `onDeviceReady()` equals here:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
```

that worked for me!!

Comment: You are calling onDeviceReady when you are defining the listener.  You should change it so that it says `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);`  This may make it so your code doesn't execute because the `deviceready` function may never fire, based on where you add this code.  Right now your code will always execute `onDeviceReady` because you're calling it right away.

Answer (score -13):

Biggest problem with PhoneGap examples are incorrect javascript syntax. Please be careful with this.. for this question,onDeviceReady should have braces...

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), true); 
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert ('123');
}
```

Comment: You're wrong. You want to pass a reference to the function, not execute it.

Comment: This is incorrect. As @DriverDan correctly suggested previously, DeviceReady should NOT have brackets in the first line, as this would result in an execution of the method rather than an assignment/reference.

Comment: You wont need the round brackets there.