# Best way to see console.log and why no alert

Tags: javascript

What is the simplest, clearest way of seeing the output of console.log events in code. I am creating an sqlite database and want to simply alert or console.log to test if it exists or not. For example, if I do this:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 5000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    if(db)
    {
        console.log("DB  created");
    alert('The database is working');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('There is a problem');
    }
}
```

I am getting no alert. Doing something wrong?

I now have this code based on this: [deviceReady not working in PhoneGap application, how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982728/deviceready-not-working-in-phonegap-application-how-to)

```
         <body onload="onDeviceReady()">

    function init(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
   // PhoneGap is ready
   //
   function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 5000);
    if(db) {
console.log('The database is working');
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB); // only do stuff if db exists
 }
  else{
console.log('There is a problem');
    }
}
```

but still no logs!

Comment: install firebug on your browser, if you didn't already.

Comment: Which browser are u testing in.. Console.log will not work in IE. So , it would have thrown error there by ceased executing the successive lines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `console` output can be seen in the dev-tools of your browser, which can be opened with <kbd>F12</kbd> on IE, FF and Chrome. After opening, switch to the `Console` tab. All output from `console.*` will be visible there.

`alert()` or other popups (`promt / confirm`) can be problematic, because it stalls your entire javascript execution until the User confirms the dialog.

Most likely you are getting no alert, because the javascript already dies on this line:

```
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
```

It should be:

```
if(db) {
    console.log('The database is working');
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB); // only do stuff if db exists
}
else{
    console.log('There is a problem');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I probably should have said that I am using Chrome. The console tab is just showing nothing. The code is exactly as it appears in the Cordova documentation. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

Comment: then most likely your function does not get executed. Set a breakpoint into that function and check if the debugger runs into it. To do so, switch to the sources tab, select the correct file and click on the line-number in question to set a breakpoint.

Comment: I tried that and no joy. Nothing showing under any of the storage in resources tab either. OK, will try he breakpoint.

Comment: So, I set a breakpoint on that function, refreshed and nothing, although a slight problem with a different function appeared. When I hover no issues appear.

Comment: Might the problem be with this  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

Comment: After I changed the code above and refreshed it worked. Happy days! Thanks.