# What does the third parameter (false) indicate in document.addEventListener("deviceready",OnDeviceReady,false);

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

What does the third parameter (false) indicate in

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",OnDeviceReady,false);
```

Can any one show an example script to show the difference

Comment: 2017 update: As [explained](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17564517/114558) by @lonesomeday, it is the [useCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) parameter.  With modern browsers, `false` is nearly always used.  Since `false` is the default setting, you can simply omit the third parameter unless you need to support truly ancient browsers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's [useCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener):

> If `true`, `useCapture` indicates that the user wishes to
>   initiate capture. After initiating
>   capture, all events of the specified
>   type will be dispatched to the
>   registered `listener` before being
>   dispatched to any `EventTarget`s beneath
>   it in the DOM tree. Events which are
>   bubbling upward through the tree will
>   not trigger a listener designated to
>   use capture. See [DOM Level 3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow)
>   for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 475):

This is for historical reasons. When the browser event system was first designed, there were two conflicting ways of modelling how it worked. They were called event capture and event bubbling.

Take for instance, this HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="#">Content</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

If an event (e.g. a click) happens on the `a` element, should the ancestor elements know? It was widely accepted that they should. But the question was *in what order* they should be notified. The Microsoft and Netscape developers (this should give you an idea of quite *how* historical we're talking!) had differing opinions.

One model was event capture (advocated by the Netscape developers). This notified the `html` element first and worked its way down the tree:

- `html`
- `body`
- `a`

The other model was event bubbling (advocated by the Microsoft developers). This notified the target element first, and worked its way up the tree:

- `a`
- `body`
- `html`

The eventual compromise was that it should do *both*.

- `html` (capture phase)
- `body` (capture phase)
- `a` (capture phase)
- `a` (bubbling phase)
- `body` (bubbing phase)
- `html` (bubbling phase)

So the event works its way down the tree and then back up again.

This is a long-winded way of getting to `addEventListener`. `addEventListener` listens for both capture phase and bubbling phase events. The third parameter (called [`useCapture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) in the specification) allows the programmer to specify which phase they want to use.

In modern browsers, this defaults to `false`. You will probably never come across a circumstance where you want to use the capturing phase, especially as Internet Explorer still doesn't support it. But old browsers need the `false` to be explicit, so it is generally provided for backwards-compatibility.

Comment: IE 9 and up now support the capturing phase.

Comment: You can get a more detailed explanation here: https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html