# e.preventDefault() not working in javascript, but working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code should work fine, but i don't know where it is getting stuck!

This code is very simple, and it should work, I think the problem is the 3rd parameter that is passed ("mouseup", function(){}, false)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>html demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<a id="navlink" href="http://google.com">Click me</a>
<div id="Reveal">Not Clicked</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('navlink').addEventListener("mouseup" , function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('reveal').innerHTML("Clicked");
    },false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its should be Uppercase 'R' in document.getElementById('reveal') as your using id name for div as Reveal

Comment: Why do you think that `e.preventDefault()`  is the problem?

Comment: `id="Reveal"` so `document.getElementById('Reveal').innerHTML = "Clicked"`

Comment: @ChakravarthySM and anup i have made another silly mistake, the code is working but it is not preventing the default function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding click event instead of mouseup.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>html demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a id="navlink" href="http://google.com">Click me</a>
      <div id="Reveal">Not Clicked</div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('navlink').addEventListener("click" , function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      //document.getElementById('reveal').innerHTML("Clicked");
      },false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul- i replaced mouseup with click and now it is working :)
Can you explain me why mouseup was not working?

Comment: Actually in hyperlink when you click its click event and not mouseup event

Comment: and what is that false in the end, i thought it works with mouseup!

Comment: It's the 3rd parameter of addEventListener juse see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Comment: Find the detailed explanation of third parameter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564323/what-does-the-third-parameter-false-indicate-in-document-addeventlistenerdev

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the innerHTML and the id of the *div Reveal*

```
document.getElementById('navlink').addEventListener("mouseup" , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('Reveal').innerHTML = "Clicked";
},false);
```

Regards.

Comment: that i changed, but the problem was due to mouseup!

Comment: Check this fiddle, is it working as you expected? http://jsfiddle.net/marioaraque/tuwcfpmj/

Comment: Actually if you click the link, the page loads and it wants to go to the link, but jsfiddle is preventing it. Try changing mouseup to click you will notice that the page doesn't load!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
document.getElementById('reveal').innerHTML = "Clicked";
```

Because `innerHTML` is property not a function.
Also you have a typo in your code, 'Reveal' is the id of DIV.

Comment: ohh man, this was a silly mistake i did there, but it is still not working for 
vaibhav thanks for replying, but can you identify any other issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following corrections, please see the snippet below

1) **`.innerHtml` is not a method, its a property** so you must use `=`

2) **`getElementById` are case sensitive** so `document.getElementById('reveal')` must be `document.getElementById('Reveal')`

```js
document.getElementById('navlink').addEventListener("mouseup" , function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('Reveal').innerHTML = "Clicked";
    },false);
```

```html
<a id="navlink" href="http://google.com">Click me</a>
<div id="Reveal">Not Clicked</div>
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Thanks Mahan, i changed the things you told me, but the problem was due to mouseup, i changed it to click and it is working fine now,
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` is a **property**, not a mutator method. The syntax are as follows:

*Return* the innerHTML property:
`HTMLElementObject.innerHTML`

*Set* the innerHTML property:
`HTMLElementObject.innerHTML=text`

In your case, it should be: `document.getElementById('reveal').innerHTML = "Clicked";`

Also, the last parameter for the `addEventListener` is optional. It is a Boolean value that specifies whether the event should be executed in the capturing or in the bubbling phase.

Comment: ok just don't use w3schools I saw you earlier you use w3schools as references

Comment: ok, i am a beginner in javascript, can you refer me some good references?

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault` does not prevent either `mouseup` or `mousedown`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21900619/1928610) answer. You must use `click()` or `addEventListener("click",` to use `preventDefault`.

Example:
`document.getElementById('navlink').addEventListener("click" , function(e){`

And in your code you made a mistake of using innerHTML as a function and `reveal` has a capital R, so the corrected form is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>html demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<a id="navlink" href="http://google.com">Click me</a>
<div id="Reveal">Not Clicked</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('navlink').addEventListener("click" , function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('Reveal').innerHTML = "Clicked";
    },false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```