# Cordova backbutton Event Never Firing

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am overriding my device back button per the documentation that I attach event listener to `backbutton` with argument of `false` after the `deviceready` event.

I have done so like this:

```
// Smart App object
define([
    'routes',
    'cordova',
    'angular',
    'angularRoute',
    'angularResource',
    'angularTouch',
    'config',
    'controllers',
    'services',
    'directives',
    'helpers'
    ], function(appRoute) {
        var oApp = {
            _app: {},

            init: function() {
                console.log('init');
                document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
            },

            onDeviceReady: function() {
                console.log('ok device ready');
                document.addEventListener('backbutton', function() {
                    console.error('deviceback start');
                    angular.element('.ng-scope').scope().back();
                    console.error('deviceback end');
                }, false);
                // ...
            }
        // ...
```

I have worked crazily to figure out why hitting the device button is not triggering this `backbutton` event i attached, i dont even see the `console.error` messages in the console. I am testing on Android right now I haven't tested on any of the other Phone OS'es yet.

The `console.log('ok device ready')` does fire and my app works properly, the device `backbutton` is overridden in that its default functionality is not taking place, however as stated, my function is not taking place either.

I read other stackoverflow topcis and they said the Cordova version landed a fix, but my Cordova version is much after theirs, my `.cordova/config.json` file tells me:

```
{
    "lib": {
        "www": {
            "id": "com.tigoenergy.smart",
            "version": "3.5.0"
        }
    }
}
```

It is `3.5` and then my `info.txt` tells me it is `5.0.0`:

```
Node version: v0.10.25

Cordova version: 5.0.0

Config.xml file: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to get console.logs of device ready and deviceback started.?

Comment: thanks @DeepMehta device ready does show in console. the deviceback started or finished dont show :(

Comment: try implementing the usual way. normally it should work. i dont see why your code is not working..

Comment: @DeepMehta by any chance would you be able to work a bit more with me on this I cant figure it out >_<

Comment: try using emulator or another device.

Comment: Found the culprit @DeepMehta ! Its line 3 https://gist.github.com/yajd/7b3243f1d6971202b46e#file-errr-js-L3 Im trying to learn angular here, in the docs what page would i look up? Im not sure what `cordova` did on this line when doing `define('app', [], function(){});` Im fairly new to angular would you know by chance? Or should i make a topic tagged angular?

Comment: Found the problem @DeepMehta! The issue was I was importing cordova.js in an iframe even though it was already in the parent window scope. I didn't know it would break.

Comment: https://github.com/sabbir456/mf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the normal way of using cordova events.

```
// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the back button
//
function onBackKeyDown() {
    //Add your back button implementation.
}
```

official documentation [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton)

Modified code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<title>Tigo SMART Installation</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="apps/installation/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="apps/installation/js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="apps/installation/js/fastclick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="apps/installation/js/sha512.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/uri.js/src/URI.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/extlogin.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="apps/installation/css/index.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(document).ready(function(){
    //mycode
    console.log('ok loaded');
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});
// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
/*function onLoad() {
console.warn('ok loaded')
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
*/

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
// Register the event listener
console.log('ok device ready');
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the back button
//
function onBackKeyDown() {
console.log('ok backey downed');
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-view></div>
<script data-main="bin/SmartApp" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.min.js"></script>

<img style="opacity:0;visibility:hidden;" class="loader" src="img/loader.gif" />
</body>
</html>
```

Few reference links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576062/jquery-document-ready-vs-phonegap-deviceready) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982728/deviceready-not-working-in-phonegap-application-how-to)

Comment: Thanks Deep I tried it this way I copied pasted: https://gist.github.com/yajd/d4836a73dc917f842dbe the load and device ready fire but when i hit back nothing happens :(

Comment: I usually import jquery first. so change the order of your imports Jquery then cordova. also you are missing ; after console.warn() in onLoad function

Comment: Thanks so much @Deep for this help I have been utterly confused on this, I tested it with this, cordova loaded last but it still didnt work :( https://gist.github.com/yajd/d4836a73dc917f842dbe/a27b2750a7eab9be9c163614b44c25045a3799eb

Comment: Thanks so much Deep for your continued help, I copeid pasted this, it said `onLoad` is not defined but i dont think this hurt it, as `ok loaded` and `ok device ready` got logged. But when i hit back button it doesnt do anything :(

Comment: yea that onload i forget it remove from body. on which phone are you testing it? try showing alerts other then console log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83005/discussion-between-deep-mehta-and-yatg).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was I was importing cordova.js in an iframe even though it was already in the parent window scope. I didn't know it would break it and thought I had to import cordova.js in the iframe. Removing the  from the iframe fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    });
    function onBackKeyDown() {
        alert('ok backey downed');
    }
```

Make sure these files are link in your page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
```