# Cordova: Device Ready not working

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Cordova to build mobile apps but for some reason device ready not fired.

Here are some of the codes.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
      alert("123");
 },true);

function plays() {
  window.HeadsetDetection.detect(function(detected) {    
    window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake()
                cordova.plugins.tonegenerator.play(650)
              })

  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    window.HeadsetDetection.registerRemoteEvents(function(status) {
        switch (status) {
            case 'headsetAdded': 
                window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake()
                cordova.plugins.tonegenerator.play(340)
            break;
            case 'headsetRemoved':
                alert('Please connect to Headset/Earpiece then play.');
            break;
        };
    });
}, true);

}


 <a class="btn btn-home" onclick="plays()"><i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i> Play</a><br><br>
```

When I click on Play button sound is playing. 
As you can see there is some alert box on device ready. Those alert are not firing.

Any advice what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deviceReady not working in PhoneGap application, how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982728/deviceready-not-working-in-phonegap-application-how-to)

Comment: @akhilesh0707 i checked that question before posting a new question. i tried that way as well but it is not working for me. Hope you understand it.

Comment: try to put your `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` after your inline js

Comment: the above code is of your `index.html`?

Comment: @akhilesh0707 yes this is index page. let me change the script tag.

Comment: take your time mate

Comment: Not working. Nothing Happend.

Comment: did you see any error? like `undefiend` function or something in the console?

Comment: it seems like cordova is not loading. Investigating it. Not sure what is happening.

Comment: try to debug using google chrome